# return an error message when the user types an incorrect input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, hide, show

this is an extension of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110766/how-to-show-hide-multiple-divs-based-on-input-value). how can i return an error message when the user types an incorrect input value? but not an alert box, i have a div that i want to appear when they enter something other than the three values i've set

```js
// Hide both <div> by default
$('#div1').hide();
$('#div2').hide();
$('#div3').hide();
$('#error').hide();

// Check on keydown
$('input').keydown(function() {
    if ($('input').val() == 'map') {  // If input value is div1
       $('#div1').slideDown();
       $('#div2').hide();
       $('#div3').hide();
       $('#error').hide();
  } else if ($('input').val() == 'derive') {  // If input value is div2
       $('#div1').hide();
       $('#div2').slideDown();
       $('#div3').hide();
       $('#error').hide();
  } else if ($('input').val() == 'glossary') {  // If input value is div3
       $('#div1').hide();
       $('#div2').hide();
       $('#div3').slideDown();
  } else if ($('input').val() == '???') {  // If input value is wrong
       $('#div1').hide();
       $('#div2').hide();
       $('#div3').hide();
       $('#error').slideDown();
  } else {
       $('#div1').hide();
       $('#div2').hide();
       $('#div3').hide();
       $('#error').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" placeholder="ENTER COMMAND" />

<div id="div1">div1 content</div>
<div id="div2">div2 content</div>
<div id="div3">div1= content</div>
<div id="error">error! unknown command</div>
```

the three values i've set are 'map' 'derive' and 'glossary'. how do i get the error div to show when the user enters any incorrect value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have built a working example for you: https://jsfiddle.net/adw8pp29/3/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Hide both <div> by default
  $('#div1').hide();
  $('#div2').hide();
  $('#div3').hide();
  $('#error').hide();

  // Check on keydown
  $('input').keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      var value = $(this).val();
      $('#div1').hide();
      $('#div2').hide();
      $('#div3').hide();
      $('#error').hide();
      if (value == 'map') { // If input value is div1
        $('#div1').slideDown();
      } else if (value == 'derive') { // If input value is div2
        $('#div2').slideDown();
      } else if (value == 'glossary') { // If input value is div3
        $('#div3').slideDown();
      } else if (value != '') { // If input value is wrong
        $('#error').html(value + " is an incorrect input value");
        $('#error').slideDown();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: this is great! but i want the div content to remain hidden until after the user presses enter, which is why i used keydown. and i also need the error div that i created to show under the input box. like for example in the snippet i posted, when you type '???' the div slides down under it. i just need '???' to represent any incorrect value.

Comment: @SLewis I updated the answer. I am not sure what you mean by  'show under the input box'. I added slideDown back in and made the function only run when the user presses enter.

Comment: this is perfect, thank you! and thanks for eliminating the extra code! i just took the "$('#error').html(value + " is an incorrect input value");" part out so only the error div slides down. it wasn't showing up when i kept that there for some reason!

Comment: @SLewis Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

```
function error(){
document.getElementByID('error').innerHTML = "error! unknown command";
}
```

call it on your // If input value is wrong
condition ..